# How to override the automatic re-orientation of images in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics

iOS 7, Xcode 5

I'm loading photos into a UIImageView and noticed that they are automatically re-oriented to display "face-up". You can see this same effect by taking 4 pictures with your phone, each time rotating the phone 90 degrees more, then viewing the images on the phone.

The problem is that I'm trying to implement some rotations after loading the image and it has the wrong effect.

For example, I have a photo taken with the iPhone vertical (home button at bottom).
When I copy the image into a UIImageView it is re-oriented face-up (without my code).
I do not want this.
And when I make another copy and apply a rotation, the rotation appears to be against the original tmp image!
What I am trying to get is an image and it's mirror.

Here's my code:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    imageTmp=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSLog(@"original orientation:%li",imageTmp.imageOrientation);
    self.imageA.image=imageTmp;
    self.imageB.image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[imageTmp CGImage]
                                          scale:1.0
                                    orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
}
```

[image]

In the screenshot above, the image on the left was taken with the phone Vertical.
I then load it into a UIImage.
Next I copy it into a UIImageView "imageA".
Last, I transform and copy the "imageTmp" into another UIImageView "imageB".
Notice that the Left image is auto-re-oriented (I do not want this!), while the right image is transformed based on the actual landscape version.

How can I prevent the auto-re-orientation?

Comment: In this case it's because `Normal` or `Up` corresponds to one of the landscape modes, at least partially to mirror the effect of traditional cameras.  If you hold your traditional camera upright and take a photo, it's landscape, not portrait.

Comment: David - yes, that's how photos work but I'm trying to override the autorotation issue.

Comment: Your code does that, by setting the orientation to Up, you effectively remove the automatic rotation that would be applied.  The photo you see on the right is the natural orientation of the image.  The camera always records a landscape image and sets the orientation to correctly display it.

Comment: There's some confusion here - the image on the right is not the natural orientation - the image on the right is the one that was rotated (as described under the screenshot). The image on the left was automatically rotated 90 degrees clockwise.

Comment: Apparently I'm not saying it clearly.  The "natural" orientation of the camera, the orientation in which it records images, is always landscape.  The pixel bytes are always organized the same way, correct for one of the landscapes (I forget which one)  It then sets standard meta data in the PNG or JFIF info that specifies an additional rotation necessary to correct for the actual camera orientation.  The image you show on the left has that automatic correction for image orientation applied.

Comment: If you take 4 photos, one in each orientation, and display the images using the CGImage and CGContextDrawImage (don't forget to flip the axis) you'll see what I'm talking about.  CGImage doesn't maintain the orientation information, so they always display with the natural orientation.  Your example code hardwires the image orientation to UIImageOrientationUpMirrored, which confuses the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the image without any implied rotation, by creating a new UIImage from the CGImage and not specifying an orientation:

```
naturalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage]];
```

Note that, as I mention in the comments above, this is always going to effectively be LandscapeRight (I think, maybe LandscapeLeft, I'm too lazy to remember which is which), as that is how the camera records the images.

Comment: David-yes, this does work to load the image in it's 'natural' state. I'm finding however, that iOS maintains a stack of transforms so that the original data is never permanently changed (which is why CGAffineTransformIdentity works to reset any image).